# How to correctly identify your phone model and version?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and I'm trying to do a fresh reinstall of Cyanongenmod.

I see in their website that there are three different versions of this phone: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#vendor=%22Google%22;searchable=%22galaxy%22;

Now I am confused and don't know which version I have? I bought it in Portugal. But is there a way to automatically identify the phone?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Go into settings then About Phone and it should display everything you need

Comment: From there I could only see that Cyanongenmod's version was implying that the phone was the maguro model. I'm not sure if that confirms that the phone is maguro as the first time I installed Cyanogenmod I might have done it wrong

Comment: Well, my assumtion is that the Cyanongenmod code get's the model using a GET command, so I'd say it was pretty accurate, I guess one way you can do it is type a model number into Google and see what model it comes up with

Comment: also what Gaurav said is a good path to take... tis a good, safe app!

Answer (score -1):

Download [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z). It helps to correctly identify your phone model, among other features.

Comment: Link for the app, a brief description and optionally, a screenshot would help.